# CakePHP saving model data to a text file

Tags: file, cakephp, text, model, datasource

is there a CakePHP DataSource for saving model data in a text file (xml, csv or other format) instead of a database or any other way to do it?. Full CRUD implementation is needed. What I have found is https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.0 but for example CsvSource only support reading model data :(

Thanks!

Comment: Well go ahead and implement writing and do a pull request.

Comment: Perhaps this might point you in the right direction: https://bitbucket.org/rotto27/cakephp-contenttextfile

Comment: Ok, is a good question but, you really need save in text files? Cannot be in sqlite? MongoDB? If you do that, you need create a method to save, read, update, etc. QUESTION: for what reason you need that? You cannot save in common database and them convert to text for do whatever you want? 

The better solution is: create your datasource and send to cakephp, or cakephp/datasources.